# Error in the Log cat Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have been using three button for this but for the good ui I chose to use 3 check boxes and a single button. Before the change everything was working fine but after the changes I did the button started throwing null pointer exception. I checked the ID of other buttons I used in the project and also the layout in which the button is present and the layout to which the java file is pointing is same. Still not able to resolve this error. Can anyone please tell me where I am doing wrong.

The XML code which points the BabyDetails activity below.

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/years03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age_group"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
        android:text="0-3 years"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age_group"
        android:text="3-6 years"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/years36"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/age_group"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="6-9 years"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:id="@+id/years69"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gotohome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/years69"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:backgroundTint="#4C0027"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
        android:text="  Next  "
        android:textSize="22sp" />
```

This is the class where the Button's action takes place.

```
public class BabyDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
CheckBox cb1,cb2,cb3;
Button gotohome;
private Baby baby;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_baby_details);
    cb1 = findViewById(R.id.years03);
    cb2 = findViewById(R.id.years36);
    cb3 = findViewById(R.id.years69);
    gotohome = findViewById(R.id.gotohome);


    gotohome.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        try {

            if(cb1.isChecked()){
                baby.setBaby_name(et_baby.getText().toString());
                baby.setBirthdate(et_date.getText().toString());
                baby.setGender(radioButton.getText().toString());
                baby.setAge("0-3 years");
                Long id = dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);
                dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);

                
                Intent intent = new Intent(BabyDetails.this, Home.class);
                intent.putExtra("added_id",id);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            else if(cb2.isChecked()){
                baby.setBaby_name(et_baby.getText().toString());
                baby.setBirthdate(et_date.getText().toString());
                baby.setGender(radioButton.getText().toString());
                baby.setAge("3-6 years");
                Long id = dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);
                dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);


                Intent intent = new Intent(BabyDetails.this, Home2.class);
                intent.putExtra("added_id",id);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else if(cb3.isChecked()){
                baby.setBaby_name(et_baby.getText().toString());
                baby.setBirthdate(et_date.getText().toString());
                baby.setGender(radioButton.getText().toString());
                baby.setAge("6-9 years");
                Long id = dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);
                dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);


                Intent intent = new Intent(BabyDetails.this, Home3.class);
                intent.putExtra("added_id",id);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            Toast.makeText(BabyDetails.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

The error in the Log cat:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.kidcave.pediacare.BabyDetails.onCreate(BabyDetails.java:50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change was required to resolve the issue. I had defined the button above the initobject function where my database was defined but after changing it works perfectly

```
    initview();
    initObject();
    cb1 = findViewById(R.id.years03);
    cb2 = findViewById(R.id.years36);
    cb3 = findViewById(R.id.years69);
    gotohome = findViewById(R.id.next03);
```